Parameterized connection in SQL transformation in Cloud Data Integration IICS
In Cloud Data Integration (CDI), when creating a mapping that has a SQL transformation inside, the connection to the SQL transformation is parameterized.
Then a mapping task has been created for the same
If the mapping task in taskflow is selected, then in the input fields, the SQL transformation connection is not listed at all

Is there any such limitation in IICS??
How can we handle such scenario??
